# Save user all filed data from registration time on frontend

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to save user all filed data from registration time on frontend. But some information save by default like name nick name but I want all information like about us, biography, DOB, etc.

[Site](http://www.gonexus360.com/mpf/register/)

```
<div class="um <?php echo $this->get_class( $mode ); ?> um-<?php echo $form_id; ?>">    
    <div class="um-form">
        <form method="post" action="">
        <?php
            do_action("um_before_form", $args);
            do_action("um_before_{$mode}_fields", $args);
            do_action("um_main_{$mode}_fields", $args);
            do_action("um_after_form_fields", $args);
            do_action("um_after_{$mode}_fields", $args);
            do_action("um_after_form", $args);
        ?>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: i am using a plugin ultimate member

Comment: <div class="um <?php echo $this->get_class( $mode ); ?> um-<?php echo $form_id; ?>">

 <div class="um-form">
 
  <form method="post" action="">
 
  <?php

   do_action("um_before_form", $args);
   
   do_action("um_before_{$mode}_fields", $args);
   
   do_action("um_main_{$mode}_fields", $args);
   
   do_action("um_after_form_fields", $args);
   
   do_action("um_after_{$mode}_fields", $args);
   
   do_action("um_after_form", $args);
   
  ?>
  
  </form>
 
 </div>
 
</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bother

[Find the link its easy](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

Comment: in your server may be location projectname/mpf/register

Comment: i used wordpress

Comment: <div class="um <?php echo $this->get_class( $mode ); ?> um-<?php echo $form_id; ?>">

 <div class="um-form">
 
  <form method="post" action="">
 
  <?php

   do_action("um_before_form", $args);
   
   do_action("um_before_{$mode}_fields", $args);
   
   do_action("um_main_{$mode}_fields", $args);
   
   do_action("um_after_form_fields", $args);
   
   do_action("um_after_{$mode}_fields", $args);
   
   do_action("um_after_form", $args);
   
  ?>
  
  </form>
 
 </div>
 
</div>